# Backbone: fetch information to model by demand

Tags: backbone.js

I want to make a Model-View behaviour in backbone.js, so that not all information will be loaded at the begining. For example I have a player infromation in the Player Model:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        },
    defaults: {
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        someOtherInfo: ...
    }
});
```

I want to show the players list in a table, where only player name and surname will be shown, however, if user clicks a player, more detailed information will be shown, by fetching other attributes (someOtherInfo).

Is there a way to do it when calling fetch?

Comment: Why not controll it in the View part? Fill the model with all data and show only things you want with `model.get`?

Comment: @LotusH There will be too much data, I want to keep load on server as less as possible

Comment: Then you have to cooperate with the server side. Adding parameter to ajax request is a good idea, e.g. `?fields=[name, suname]` and use `fetch({data:{fields:[name, surname]}})`

Comment: @LotusH, The server side will be different than backbone. Do you mean that request such as: model.fetch({data:{fields:[name, surname]}}) will fetch only surname and name for Player model?

Comment: `fetch({data:xxx})` is like `$.ajax({data:xxx})`, it just add the `data` you specify to the `GET` parameter in the URL. You have to write the corresponding logic on the server side to make this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your API methods returning the list/collection can return different data than the API method for fetching a specific model. Just populate the collection with only the data needed for the list and when an item is selected fetch that specific model to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I need some data from server to populate the model. But not all at once. I can't populate it without making request to server

Comment: I mean the `GET /players` request (from collection.fetch()) used to populate the collection can return just (id, name, surname) e.g. `[{id:1, name:"first", surname:"last"}, {id:2, name:"some", surname:"other"}, ...]` for each object in the list whereas the `GET /players/1` request (from model.fetch()) should return everything (id, name, surname, someOtherInfo)